# News Articles: Write to server disk without PHP?

Tags: java, javascript, html, applet

I'm looking into a small project just now where we have a need for a very very basic news article system. Ideally, this is a simple XML file that will be written to with some news, and then parsed to display on the homepage. This file is on the server, of course.

My question is how to allow a client browser to write to this XML file, given that the server will not have PHP enabled?

I know of TiddlyWiki which uses a .JAR file to allow the writes, but are there any other methods I should try?

Comment: So are you staying there's NO server side scripting language installed, or just not PHP? (Is Tomcat in use for example?)

Comment: @middaparka: I've been directed that MySQL/PHP are not installed. It's running on Apache. AFAIK Tomcat will not be installed, otherwise I'd roll some JSP pages.
@Oli: FTP would suit me, but probably not the end user who will maintain the news :)

Comment: Does the server support CGI at all?  There has to be *something* on the server or else it's impossible.  The example of TiddlyWiki is incorrect - that tool only writes files on the **client**, not a server, and only when it's run as a local ("file://") URL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since FTP seems to be enabled/supported, your best bet is to create an applet which does the job. FTP connectivity can fairly simple be done by [Apache Commons Net FTPClient](http://commons.apache.org/net/api/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html). Your only problem is that the FTP connection details needs to be embedded in the applet somehow and that anyone with bad intent can extract it from the applet's source code since applets are downloaded into the client machine.

Answer (score 1):

Without some serverside code, you will not be able to write files to the server.

You need a "PHP/Java/FTP-Server/something else"-backend serverprocess to take the content and write it to a file.

Answer (score 1):

[Apache supports HTTP PUT](http://www.apacheweek.com/features/put), and [some browsers](http://annevankesteren.nl/2007/10/http-method-support) support it in XMLHttpRequest. So long as you are willing to limit editors to browsers that support it, you could use that without installing additional software on the server or using a plugin on the client.

Answer (score 0):

FTP would definitely work, depending on how well the user doing the updates is familiar with it.

If the upload solution needs to be browser-based, you could perhaps run an [FTP applet](http://www.google.com/search?q=ftp+applet) and have the user remember the connection details/password.